# Format for cell phone without margin

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am new to responsive CSS. The code below is a template for a responsive html page. I would like it to normally have 25px margins, but for a cell phone there should not be any margins. I have tried as many combinations of adjustments as I can think of. For example I tried changing the left/right margins for column 1 and 12 for @media but that did not work.

What must I do ?

```css
body { margin:25px; }

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row:after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
   float: left;
   padding-top: 15px;
   width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%; }
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%; }
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%; }
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%; }
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%; }
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%; }
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%; }
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%; }
    
  .col-s-9 {
     width: 75%;
     padding: 15px;
  }
      
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%; }
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%; }
    
  .col-s-12 {
     width: 100%;
     padding:15px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%; }
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%; }
    .col-3 {width: 25%; }
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%; }
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%; }
    
    .col-6 {
      width: 50%;
      padding:0px 15px 15px 15px;
    }
    
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%; }
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%; }
    .col-9 {width: 75%; }
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%; }
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%; }
    
    .col-12 {
      width: 100%;
      padding:15px;
    }
}

html { font-family: arial; }

.header {
   background-color: #9933cc;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 .menu li {
   padding: 8px;
   margin-bottom: 7px;
   background-color :#33b5e5;
   color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.menu li:hover { background-color: #0099cc; }

.aside {
   background-color: #33b5e5;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 14px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.footer {
   background-color: #0099cc;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>The Island of Crete</h1>
  </div>
    
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-3 col-s-3 menu">
      <ul>
        <li>The Flight</li>
        <li>The City</li>
        <li>The Island</li>
        <li>The Food</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-6 col-s-9">
      <h1>Chania - A great city</h1>
      <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
      <!--<img src="img_chania.jpg" width="460" height="345">-->
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-3 col-s-12">
      <div class="aside">
        <h2>What?</h2>
        <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
        
        <h2>Where?</h2>
        <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
        
        <h2>How?</h2>
        <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you are using giving the `body` a margin of `25px` at :

```
body { margin:25px; }
```

but then not changing it as per your requirements for smaller screens. You are correct in the need for using `@media`, but the implementation does not modify the `margin` further.

So basically, what needs to be done is :

```
/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, 
    remove the margin 
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks. I was attempting to set it in the wrong place :(

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the body is set to have a margin of 25px at the top of your stylesheet - therefore regardless of what you do with the column sizes, it will always use the 25px margin for the page as a whole.

In your media queries, insert the following:

```
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

As the media queries take place lower down the page than your initial assignment, it will override the previous margin - please note that this won't always work for higher end phones with high resolution screens (for example, the Galaxy S8 has a resolution width of 1440px).